# How to make GridView take me to a different page

Tags: c#, json, gridview, windows-store-apps

I;m new on SO so please be gentle. I searched and didn't find what I was looking for.

My problem is as follows - I am making a game for Windows Store where you must finish sentences based on the animation you see below the sentence. The game will offer many stories and this is my problem. I used the default GridView template to create the MENU for picking your stories. And this is where I am stuck:

How to tell the app using json that when clicked it should open a specific page (the wanted level)?

This is the code that I need to change probably:

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
            // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
            var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
        }
```

I know that I need to change the last line so that it takes some information from the json file and changes it for a specific page file name from the solution.

I hope that you understand what I mean :(

Comment: the data you want to use is SampleDataItem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the template field to add a button with your routing argument.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Action" CommandName="Action"
 CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID ") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Action")
{
string ID = e.CommandArgument; // Do something with it. 
}
```